# jsp simply code throwing a nullPointerException

Tags: jsp

Here is the test.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
    String str = request.getParameter("str");
    if (str.equals("play")) {
    }                  
%>
```

Errors:

> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ```
> root cause java.lang.NullPointerException
> ```
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs.

The above code have errors if run, what the problems of above codes?

Comment: Add str!=null to your if loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  `if (str.equals("play"))` to  `if (str!=null && str.equals("play"))`

Your request parameter is null it seems.

Answer (score 1):

**Having scriptlets in jsp is very bad programming practise.**

For the problem you are facing , i think the **parameter is not found**. **Check if the parameter is being sent for the request**.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this. If you have constant string e.g. in your case "play" compare with it the variable rather than what you are doing. i.e.

```
 if ( ("play").equals(str))
 {

 }
```

In this way you wont get Null Pointer exception because String is not equal to null (if str is null).  In your case since str is null so null.equals is giving you null pointer exception.

Also trying printing out the value of str before if statement like below to see what value is coming.

```
out.println("Str:"+str);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no request parameter for `"str"` so the str variable is `null`. As others suggested you might use this `"play".equals(str);`.

Answer (score 0):

Please debug the .java file from where you are getting the "str" value from.
And check if you are getting a null in that position.
If yes, Then that is why it is throwing a NULL Pointer Exception.
Str!=NULL would not solve your problem as you would not get the desired output & lead to your confusion even more.
PS : Please avoid using scriptlets in JSP.